Trying to implement graceful shutdown in spring boot 2 application running in kubernetes
I am trying to implement graceful shutdown in our spring boot 2 application to remove 5xx errors when scale down of pods occurs
I have set
management:
  endpoints:
    jmx: 
      exposure:
        include: "*"
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true

server.shutdown: graceful

inside my application.yaml file and I am using /actuator/health endpoint as my liveness and readiness probe inside my deployment.yaml file.
I have set a sleep period of 50 seconds inside preStopHook and my terminationGracePeriod is 120 seconds
My deployment.yaml file
lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 50;","rm -rf /mnt/bixby/log/$HOSTNAME"]
terminationGracePeriod: 120

livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8080
      path: /actuator/health
    initialDelaySeconds: 45
    periodSeconds: 5
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8080
      path: /actuator/health
    initialDelaySeconds: 45
    periodSeconds: 5

The weird thing is this thing is working in one environment (let's call it dev1) but not in other (dev2).
When I delete a pod and when I send a curl request to /actuator/health endpoint it returns {"status":"DOWN","groups":["liveness","readiness"]} in dev1 but it doesn't returns any response in dev2 env. I get the following output curl: (52) Empty reply from server after 50 seconds which is also my prestopHook sleep time. And weirdly our own custom health check endpoint which we used earlier returns correct response during this period
After that if i do a curl request again i get following output
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 0

Also strangely in dev1 env where graceful shutdown seems to work properly the pod exits after 50 seconds which is weird since terminationGracePeriod is 120 seconds
I have added the following predestroy code in my spring boot application
@PreDestroy
  public void tearDown() {
    logger.log("Application shutting down");
  }

All the configuration, docker image of spring boot application, kubernetes version in both env are same.
I have also added this swagger configuration for actuator to work together with swagger
 @Bean // This bean is required when you want swagger and actuator to work together
 public static BeanPostProcessor springfoxHandlerProviderBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
      @Override
      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) 
          throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider 
            || bean instanceof RequestHandlerProvider) {
          customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(getHandlerMappings(bean));
        }
        return bean;
      }

      private <T extends RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> void customizeSpringfoxHandlerMappings(
          List<T> mappings) {
        List<T> copy = mappings.stream().filter(mapping -> mapping.getPatternParser() == null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        mappings.clear();
        mappings.addAll(copy);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      private List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping> getHandlerMappings(Object bean) {
        try {
          Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(bean.getClass(), "handlerMappings");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          return (List<RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping>) field.get(bean);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
      }
    };
  }


A few things: Springboot provides liveness and readiness probes, so you don't have to use /actuator/health
In your application.yaml, do:
management:
  health:
    livenessState:
      enabled: true
    readinessState:
      enabled: true

Then in your deployment yaml:
livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8080
      path: /actuator/health/liveness
    initialDelaySeconds: 45
    periodSeconds: 5
readinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      port: 8080
      path: /actuator/health/readiness
    initialDelaySeconds: 45
    periodSeconds: 5

Also, the pod exiting after 50 seconds is correct. If graceful shutdown only takes 50 seconds, there is no reason for the pod to wait beyond that. If it is always waiting 120 seconds, then graceful shutdown is not happening properly. You should see "Graceful shutdown completed" at the end of the log so verify it like that.
As for the graceful shutdown working in 1 env but not the other, that is indeed strange. Is the deployment file used the exact same one? How are you starting the application? If you want to really verify that the shutdown is working, you best option is to look at the application log.

Is the deployment file used the exact same one? Yes
How are you starting the application?
I am starting it using a shell script and inside script i am trapping SIGTERM and then propagating the SIGTERM to child application process
But when I kill -TERM the shell script PID from inside the pod the pod exited immediately in both env

How are you trapping and propagating it? Are you using exec when running the command? Are you running any other commands before the application run command in the script?

I am storing the id of the process when running the java application command (let's call it app_id) . Then I am using trap for the SIGTERM signal and inside the that i am executing kill -TERM app_id

Yes I am executing pkill before application run command to kill any zombie application process

i will share the sample script in some time

#! /bin/sh
Function to handle SIGTERM
cleanup() {
echo "Received SIGTERM, cleaning up..."
# If a child process is running, send SIGTERM to it
if [ -n "$child_pid" ]; then
    kill -TERM "$child_pid"
    
    # Optionally, wait for the child process to exit
    wait "$child_pid"
    
fi

exit 0

}
trap cleanup TERM
java application run &
child_pid=$!
echo "Started child process (PID $child_pid). Waiting for it to complete..."
wait "$child_pid"
echo "Child process (PID $child_pid) completed. Exiting script."

I don't think the process is being considered by Kubernetes since it is something like a background process. Add exec before the java process is started and see if that helps. Is there any reason you are trapping the term at all?

Today I tried with exec to make the application as process id1. I am still getting same issue of 502 and 504 status error on load testing while deleting one of the pod in between. On sending kill -TERM to process inside of pod after exec into it the pod exits immediately. Is this normal behaviour?
